# Aws s3 file name is not printing using batch file in echo function

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-s3, command-line

I am using a windows batch script to print the Aws s3 ls filename from the bucket by using this code.

```
@echo off
echo
set files =aws s3 ls "s3://my-test-files/01_Jan_2021.zip"   

echo.%files%

pause
```

but when I run this command "aws s3 ls "s3://my-test-files/01_Jan_2021.zip" directly on cmd it gives me the file name but when I use this in the windows batch script and echo the file name it is not printing the name.

@Mic: your given solution provides me that data but I want to extract only the highlighted portion that is "01_Jan_2021.zip"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're seeking?

```batch-file
@Set "files=aws s3 ls "s3://my-test-files/01_Jan_2021.zip""
@For /F "Tokens=3,* Delims= " %%G In ('%files%') Do @Echo=%%H
@Pause
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the space in `set files =` command:

```
@echo off

set "files=aws s3 ls "s3://my-test-files/01_Jan_2021.zip""
%files%

pause
```

Comment: now it is echo the whole command "aws s3 ls "s3://my-test-files/01_Jan_2021.zip"".I think I has to be wait until this command return some value and than echo

Comment: try to remove `echo` at second line, see if it changes.

Comment: @Novapex The output you get is different from if you call it from cmd directly?

Comment: I think the issue is due to set the output to a variable that is "set files".
because when I put this command directly in the .bat file without assigning it to a variable it prints the file name but when I'm assigning a variable to it and then print that variable it causes an issue and prints nothing

Comment: why you put the variable name "files" into double quotes?

Comment: the syntax `set "variable=whatever you type here"` is safer than `set variable=whatever you type here`, it avoids misspelling when you have special characters.

As last, instead of `echo.%files%` try simply `%files%`. I edited the answer. This should solve the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question after applying your solution plz look into it.

Comment: Sorry, not much clear what is the problem now. So, now you get the desired solution, but ?
from you comment is seems it extracts something else/more, is it? I don't know the command `aws`, so you should explain better how it works, and what it desires as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set files=aws s3 ls "s3://my-test-files/01_Jan_2021.zip
cls
echo %files%
pause
```

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working just echo the whole command
"aws s3 ls "s3://my-test-files/01_Jan_2021.zip"